# Zoomable Treemap Template v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to convert 
http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022 from d3 v3 to d3 v4. 
I'm having an issue where treemap.nodes() no longer exists and I can't seem to find a way to replace it in v4.

Here is what I have done so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/YmVZKs5xPjmoZid1HmCM?p=preview

```
        function layout(d) {
            if (d._children) {
                treemap.nodes({ _children: d._children });
                d._children.forEach(function (c) {
                    c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
                    c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
                    c.dx *= d.dx;
                    c.dy *= d.dy;
                    c.parent = d;
                    layout(c);
                });
            }
        }
```

[Zoomable Treemap d3.v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454785/zoomable-treemap-d3-v4) 
This question was asking about the same template and converting it to v4, but doesn't mention how they fixed the issue with treemap.nodes()